# Where Clause - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am new to Ruby on Rails and am having trouble with a simple where with a model.

When I try to do Test #1 the results are out of order. New items get pushed to the bottom no matter what.

```
    def index
    @user = User.where(:status => false).order(last_name: :desc).all
    end
```

If I enter this into rails console it doesn't work also but if I remove the all it works perfectly in rails console but doesn't work in the UsersController.

What is the proper way to do a where clause with an order? Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:**

I have updated the code to the following but the results are still out of order:

```
    def index
        @user = User.where(status: false).order('last_name DESC')
    end
```

Comment: you are ordering by `last_name` and not `id` which would most likely guarantee having new items ordered correctly (if you are using rails default for id generation: auto-incrementing the ids)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `order('last_name DESC')` instead of `order(last_name: :desc)`.

`order(last_name: :desc)` will produce sql like (That's why your order doesn't work):

```
ORDER BY '---\\n:last_name: :desc\\n'
```

`order('last_name DESC')` will produce sql right:

```
ORDER BY last_name DESC
```

Comment: Right, `order` YAMLizes a Hash argument for some strange reason that might have sounded like a good idea after too many bottles of hard liquor. I can't see why you'd ever want to put a YAML string in an ORDER BY, that just doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: So is the .all at the end not needed?

Comment: @evanvee: No, the query will hit the database when you try to read values from it by doing something like `@users.each { ... }`. And that variable really should be called `@users` rather than `@user`.

Comment: I know have it listed like this but the results are still out of order? `@user = User.order('last_name DESC').where(status: false)`

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4

```
def index
    @user = User.where(status: false).order('last_name DESC')
end
```

Comment: So is the .all at the end not needed?

Comment: Correct if your using rails 4.